# Probability of Drawing All Cards in Multiple Selections

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

Let's assume we have a deck of four different cards. If I select randomly a card and the put it back into the deck then what is the probability that I will see all of the four different cards in 5 draws?

This is a simplified version of a problem I have to solve.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt at solving this simplified problem:

- number of ways to get 4 different cards in 5 draws:  $\binom{5}{4}*4!*4$

  because we choose 4 out of the 5 cards which are going to be the ones that will contain all of the different cards, $4!$ ways to choose the 4 different cards and 4 cards left for the fifth card
- number of possible draws: $4^5$

If we divide these two numbers we get: $\frac{\binom{5}{4}*4!*4}{4^5} = 0.46875$

However a simple C++ script that I ran gave the answer: $23.4516$% which is approximately one half of the answer I got. Could someone help me? It would be really nice if someone specified the corresponding answer for the case where we draw more than 5 cards.

Comment: The general question is related to the coupon collector's problem.  

The probability of having seen all $k$ cards in $n$ draws with replacement is $\dfrac{k! \, S_2(n,k)}{k^n}$, 

where $S_2(n,k)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). 

With $n=5, k=4$ you have $S_2(5,4)=10$, making the probability $\dfrac{4! \times 10}{4^5}\approx 0.234$.

Comment: You counted each selection twice, once for each way you could have designated one of the two positions in the sequence of draws in which the card that appears twice appears as the position in the sequence in which that card appears.

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much. The problem I had to solve was very similar to the coupon collector's problem. I will look into the Stirling numbers of the second kind cause I don't think I quite get them right now.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Do you mean that I count cases like (abcda) two times for the two different permutations of the two 'a's?

Comment: @Henry Is there an intuitive answer to why $\dfrac{k! \, S_2(n,k)}{k^n}$ this formula you provided is correct? I mean I get the use of Stirling numbers of the second kind in general (the ways to partion a set on n objects into k non-empty subsets) however I can't understand how this definition applies to this problem.

Comment: @NickTsiodras You have given the definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind including the crucial "non-empty": this is for unlabelled partitions.  Your problem here has labels (the values of the $k$ different cards) so you need to multiply by $k!$ to get a count of how many equally-likely possibilities there are here, and then divide by $k^n$ to get a probability

Comment: @Henry Sorry for being so bad but I still can't wrap my head around what you're saying. The term $k!S_2(n,k)$ should count how many possible ways you can draw n cards and they will contain all of the k different cards. How does $k!$ multiplied by the number of possible partitions of a set of n objects into k non-empty subsets give us that result? I think I'm just having a a brain-fart right now and the answer is right in front of me so I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I mean that by choosing one of the $a$s to be the designated $a$ in that permutation, you count the permutation twice, once for each way you could designate one of the two $a$s as the $a$ in that permutation.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig One of the $10$ partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ into four non-empty parts counted by $S_2(5,4)$ might be $\{1,3\},\{2\},\{4\},\{5\}$.  In this question, that partition might correspond to the five-card draw $abacd$ where the first and third draws are the same card i.e. with $\{1,3\}$; but it could equally correspond to $cacdb$ or $adabc$ or any of $4!$ possible way of allocating the four cards to the four parts with the first and third draws the same and the others different.

Answer (score 2):

Close.

The denominator of $~4^5~$ is good.

For the numerator, once you apply the $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1}~$ factor to determine which card will be drawn twice, you then have to determine which $~2~$ of the $~5~$ positions for which that card will occur.  Then, you need the $~3!~$ factor to dispense with the three remaining cards.

So, the numerator should be

$$\binom{4}{1} \times \binom{5}{2} \times 3!.$$

Note that my computation above results in
a probability of

$$\frac{240}{1024} = 23.4375\%.$$

Comment: Thank you very much